# Test for NaN in java

Tags: java, android

I'm wondering if there is a way to test for NaN in java. The code below is returning NaN where it should be returning "NA".

```
if (tempAlloc == Double.NaN) {
                tv4.setText("NA");
            } else {
                tv4.setText(customFormat("###.#%",
                        Double.toString(tempAlloc)));
            }
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Usa [`Double.isNaN(tempAlloc)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#isNaN%28double%29). It returns `true`, when the argument is `NaN` and `false` otherwise.

This is implemented by checking if the argument is not equal to itself (a unique property of `NaN` values):

```
boolean isNaN == tempAlloc != tempAlloc;
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean here and how to implement it in the code above.

Comment: @cfarm54: `Double.isNaN()` returns `true` when the argument is `NaN`. So simply replace `tempAlloc == Double.NaN` in your code with `Double.isNaN(tempAlloc)`.

Comment: use `if (Double.isNaN(tempAlloc))` `NaN` aren't equal to themselves.